# Json Url Query Always Generate Same Values

Tags: jsonresult

I have Asp.Net MVC project. I generate a json from JsonResult. However I cant use url query. It will get always all values.

Here my Json Result method:

```
 public JsonResult GetAllBanks()
    {
        BankService _srvBank = new BankService();
        List<TblBank> allBanks = _srvBank.GetBanks();
        List<Bank> banks = new List<Bank>();
        foreach (var bank in allBanks)
        {
            Bank b = new Bank();
            b.value = bank.BankName;
            banks.Add(b);
        }
        return Json(banks,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Here the json method generate:

```
http://localhost:6845/supplier/suppliercompany/getallbanks

[{"value":"Adabank A.Ş."},{"value":"Akbank T.A.Ş."},
 {"value":"Aktif Yatırım Bankası A.Ş."},{"value":"Albaraka Türk Katılım Bankası A.Ş."},
  {"value":"Alternatifbank A.Ş."},{"value":"Anadolubank A.Ş."},
  {"value":"Arap Türk Bankası A.Ş"},{"value":"Bank Mellat Türkiye"}]
```

However url query does not work. I get Always the same values:

```
http://localhost:6845/supplier/suppliercompany/getallbanks?value=sometext

 [{"value":"Adabank A.Ş."},{"value":"Akbank T.A.Ş."},
 {"value":"Aktif Yatırım Bankası A.Ş."},{"value":"Albaraka Türk Katılım Bankası A.Ş."},
  {"value":"Alternatifbank A.Ş."},{"value":"Anadolubank A.Ş."},
  {"value":"Arap Türk Bankası A.Ş"},{"value":"Bank Mellat Türkiye"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the problem is you have to build your application to profile it.

At work we had a couple of projects written outside which we load-tested before putting them on our main boxes. We were quite surprised to find critical performance problems with both; one was written in CakePHP and the other was written using Drupal. I don't think this highlights a problem with any framework or CMS other than the need to do profiling and load-testing on any site which is going to get significant traffic. In both cases it was what the developer had done, rather than the characteristics of the software platform, that caused the problem. For example, there was a recursive function call the developer had created in the Cake project which instantiated the entire Cake object every recursion and this would have taken out the server had it gone live under load.

In my opinion performance should not be a deciding factor in choosing a framework; the objective differences are likely to be marginal and the way you use it is likely to cause far more performance problems than the inherent performance of the framework.

I believe that to scale any PHP application to run under load, you will need an opcode cache and you'll need to write in intelligent content caching using something like memcached or whatever built-in caching your framework supports.

Comment: Thank you but I dont understand clearly what should I do

Comment: I use Asp.Net not php